# removal of hyphens only after 10 characters

Tags: notepad++

I have data that has'-' in between.
the hyphens are included in the data too.
I want to delete the hyphens after every 10 characters but not the ones included within the data.
Example:

```
GSVGPGLLGV-STLGPKRNSM-VLDVAFVLEG-SDKIGE-----RSKEFMEEVI
```

the want this way:

```
GSVGPGLLGVSTLGPKRNSMVLDVAFVLEGSDKIGE----RSKEFMEEVI
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A REGEX is what you need.

Do a Replace

- Find What: `([^\r\n-]{10})-([^\r\n-])`
- Replace With: `$1$2`
- Search Mode Regular Expression

You will probably need to Replace All until you get 0 occurrence was replaced.

Updated:

I'm still fuzzy on what you're trying to do, but try this instead.

Do a Replace

- Find What: `([^\r\n-]{10})-`
- Replace With: `$1`
- Search Mode Regular Expression

Comment: GSVGPGLLGV-STLGPKRNSM-VLDVAFVLEG-SDKIGEADFN-RSKEFMEEVI

------------------------EEEEEEE---TTT-HHHHH-HHHHHHHHHH-

Could you help me remove hyphens in the second line too (after 10 hyphens) corresponding to first?
I mean to say after removal of hyphens in both the lines the number of characters should match

Comment: GSVGPGLLGV-STLGPKRNSM-VLDVAFVLEG-SDKIGEADFN-RSKEFMEEVI

------------------------EEEEEEE---TTT-HHHHH-HHHHHHHHHH-

should look like
1-  GSVGPGLLGVSTLGPKRNSMVLDVAFVLEGSDKIGEADFNRSKEFMEEVI
  ----------------------EEEEEEE--TTT-HHHHHHHHHHHHHHH

Comment: I am not understanding something.

If you remove hyphens, how can the number of characters in the line match, and match to what?

Comment: here is the data
(1)MGSDKIHHHH-HHMPKVTVSI-KVVPAVEDGR-LHEVIDRAIE-KISSWGMKYE
(2)----------------EEEEE-EEEESS-GGG-HHHHHHHHHH-HHHTT-SEEE
(3)VGPSNTTVEG-EFEEIMDRVK-ELARYLEQFA-KRFVLQLDID-YKAGGITIEE
(4)E-SS-EEEEE--HHHHHHHHH-HHHHHHTTT--SEEEEEEEEE-EETT---HHH
(5)KVSKYR
(6)HHGGG-

The hyphens have to be removed after 10 characters in all 6 lines of data. After the removal of hyphens, the number of characters in line (1) has to equal (2),(3)&(4), (5)&(6)

Comment: (1)MGSDKIHHHHHHMPKVTVSIKVVPAVEDGRLHEVIDRAIEKISSWGMKYE
(2)---------------EEEEEEEEESS-GGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHTT-SEEE
(3)VGPSNTTVEGEFEEIMDRVKELARYLEQFAKRFVLQLDIDYKAGGITIEE
(4)E-SS-EEEEE-HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHTTT-SEEEEEEEEEEETT---HHH
(5)KVSKYR
(6)HHGGG-

That is how I need. 
If I used ([^\r\n-]{10})-([^\r\n-]) the hyphens in line 2 are not getting replaced.

Comment: In order for the number of characters in the lines to be equal after hyphens are removed, are you wanting to pad the lines with spaces? If so, how long should the lines be?

Comment: ok, let me make it easy for you.

([^\r\n-]{10})-([^\r\n-]) works for this line:
SNASVIVGRA-LPEVRDGLKP-VHRRVLYAMF-DSGFRPDRSH-AKSARSVAET

but help me remove hyphens after 10 characters in this line too
-------TTT-S-BTTT---H-HHHHHHHHHH-HHT--TTS---EEHHHHHHHH
after the removal of hyphens the above should be
-------TTTS-BTTT---HHHHHHHHHHHHHT--TTS--EEHHHHHHHH

Comment: If you're wanting to change this:
`-------TTT-S-BTTT---H-HHHHHHHHHH-HHT--TTS---EEHHHHHHHH`

To this:
`-------TTTS-BTTT---HHHHHHHHHHHHHT--TTS--EEHHHHHHHH`

Then you're coming up with a different pattern that I'm not seeing.

Comment: can I get ur mail ID plz
-------TTT-S-BTTT---H-HHHHHHHHHH-HHT--TTS---EEHHHHHHHH
I need to remove hyphens after 10 characters in the above line.